# How do I layout a UITableViewCell using only frames (no Auto Layout)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, frame

This may sound like a silly question, but most of my experience with iOS development has revolved around Auto Layout being prominent, and I'm curious now (for performance purposes) how I'd go about laying out a cell without Auto Layout and using only frames (and perhaps auto-resizing masks). Turns out this is very hard to Google due to the prominence of Auto Layout.

Essentially am I setting up and adding the subviews in the `initWithStyle` method of the `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Positioning wise, am I just relying on the `bounds` of the `contentView`, and then if I want one view beside another view, would I basically do `newView.frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(otherView.frame) + spacing`?

What happens when I rotate? I know I can watch for rotation in `viewWillTransitionToSize`, but how do I go about re-positioning the cells? Simply calling `tableView.reloadData()` would be both expensive and not do much as the cells are laid out in `initWithStyle`, correct?

I'm targeting iOS 8+.

Any insight would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually its

```
newView.frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(otherView.frame) + spacing + leftMargin;

// you have to include all the spacing, including margins
```

Tip:

Do not rely on `bounds of the contentView` by default it is set to maximum width of `320`, i suggest you use main screen's frame for that.

AutoLayout is our friend and can save us a lot of time.

> how do I go about re-positioning the cells?

If you're planning to do it programmatically, you need to setup the new height and width of the view after the rotation.

Calling `tableView.reloadData()` to update the views in the cell is not expensive, that's how it works. We don't have a choice but to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Then it will be better to write the frame calculation portion in viewDidLayoutSubViews.

Comment: Do you mean `layoutSubviews`? The method you quoted is a `UIViewController` method.

Comment: If you are in ViewController its viewDidLayoutSubViews. But you are in UITableViewCell (subClass of UIView) so you write frame calculation part in `layoutSubViews`. My mistake... :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I understand your question. Please let me know if this makes sense:

#### Adding Subviews

To add subviews programmatically, it's actually best to do so in the override of `layoutSubviews` by checking if the contentView has subviews already added and calling a method to add them if needed. This way, you can load the table cell via either a storyboard/nib or using initWithStyle. Alternatively, you can use a shared `commonInit` method that you call in both initWithCoder and initWithStyle.

#### Layout of Subviews

To layout your subviews programmatically, you override `layoutSubviews` (and remember to call super) and set up the frames in that method. This method will be called whenever the view changes size (rotation, initial presentation, etc) and will always include the current bounds of the content view. To calculate your subview frames, you can do so as you've suggested, but you need to define the subview frame and then set the frame for the view:

```
frameB.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(viewA.frame) + spacing;
viewB.frame = frameB;
```

And keep in mind that this will *not* correct for the width of frameB. Therefore, you might want to consider using `CGRectDivide()` instead.

#### Scrolling performance

That said, the big performance hit when using auto layout in table view cells is *not* auto layout itself, but the calculations that are done many times on the same set of data to lay it out - all on the main thread. Such as calculating frames for all the text to layout a bunch of labels relative to one another or something that uses drawRect rather than drawing to an image bitmap on a background thread and then loading the image in to a UIImageView once the drawing is complete. Without knowing what data you are displaying it is hard to guess what is causing the performance issues, but you should be sure to use profiling to determine if you are actually improving performance. Additionally, you may need to consider moving some of the number crunching and/or image rendering onto a background thread.

Good luck!